# C++ CLI drawing lines

Tags: visual-c++, command-line-interface

I have 2 circles. I want to make a line between them by clicking on once circle, dragging the the mouse to the second circle, and releasing the click. How is this possible in visual 2008 c++ cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly keep track of the circles you have. Then you'd have to handle the MouseDown/MouseMove/MouseUp events and determine where these occur and then use this to draw the line.

Comment: How will my goal be achieved by these events?